# make div fill the rest of the browser viewport

Tags: html, css, position

so i have a normal 960px layout, i want to add a div that can use 300px inside that 960 and the rest of the space (browser width) i want to fill with that div...but always stay on the same position inside the wrapper (im not talking about a vertical fixed element)

can i do this without using javascript? but if theres isnt another option its ok

[image: how to fill the red divs to browser width without using javascript?]

Example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fill">Something</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    background: #ddd;
}
.fill {
    margin: 300px 0 0 0;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;    
}
```

thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Your description and picture are confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood what you need: try this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jGmcV/show/ 
http://jsfiddle.net/jGmcV/ (source)

this should be the effect, but I placed an extra wrapper around your `wrapper`. The width of red box inside the dark container is always of 300px no matter what the size of the viewport is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin-left:-10%; and margin-right:-10%;
If i understood correctly.

or you can

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    background: #ddd;
    position:relative;
}
.fill {
    margin: 300px 0 0 0;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;    
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:-10%;
}
```

Comment: yeah but the thing is, i need to set the width of that div and i cant match all the resolutions doing that..and i cant do it by using "%".. the only option would be to use javascript...

Comment: you can use max and min width